# UIImagePicker Controller in Landscape mode

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I have used one `UIImagePicker Controller` in my game. its working fine in iPad Landscape mode using `UIPopOver Controller` but as `UIPopoverController` is not supported in iPhone I have used `UIIMagePicker Controller` for iPhone.
now, it crashes in my iPhone. please help me.

I have select following Orientation in Deplyoment Info of my project :

Landscape Left
Landscape Right

Comment: Collect log error and put here.

Comment: @HaroldoGondim there is no error log but it crashes on main file at this line ....   int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppController");
    [pool release];
    return retVal;

Comment: @HaroldoGondim I guess , it requires portrait mode enable in device orientations in deployment info section . but i haven't select their because it affects my overall UI integration.

Answer (score 0):

The UIImagePickerController only support's portrait, so you must make sure your app has portrait as a supported orientation. Please see the [UIImagePickerController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/) documentation, I have included a quote from the document.

> IMPORTANT
>
> The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This
> class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.
> The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified,
> with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the
> cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional
> information or manage the interactions between the camera interface
> and your code.

---

EDIT

Look at the [UIApplicationDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:), it has the following method

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask
```

From the documentation:

> **Discussion**
>
> This method returns the total set of interface orientations
> supported by the app. When determining whether to rotate a particular
> view controller, the orientations returned by this method are
> intersected with the orientations supported by the root view
> controller or topmost presented view controller. The app and view
> controller must agree before the rotation is allowed.
>
> If you do not implement this method, the app uses the values in the
> UIInterfaceOrientation key of the app’s Info.plist as the default
> interface orientations.

---

Comment: yea . thanks but for only supporting UIImagePickerController i need to enable Portrait mode and doing that it affects my overall UI which is fully in landscape mode. please tell me if you have any suggetions.

Comment: right now i have solved my issue with this following  method but i am not sure its valid or not  
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if ([self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass: [UIImagePickerController class]])
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
    else return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

Comment: What method did you use?

Comment: If this is called on device rotation, not just at app launch, you may have your solution which is  and as stated in my answer your app must support portrait orientation for the UIImagePickerController.

Comment: this method in appdelegate > supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow